# How to change Visual Studio Team Services Repository at Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control, azure-pipelines

How to change Visual Studio Team Services Repository at Android Studio?

I create a repo at  `user1.visualstudio.com` at 'my repo' repository;
I install VSTS plugin at Android Studio.
Then, i want to push at another repository: `user2.visualstudio.com` instead `user1.visualstudio.com`, but i can not!

I try to change this version control settings:

```
1.Remove VSTS plugin
2. Set up VSTS plugin
3.Log out from VSTS window.
```

But, when i push code- is pushes at `user1.visualstudio.com`.

How to change it to `user2.visualstudio.com`?

EDIT: I create another `my repo` repository at `user2.visualstudio.com` and want to start pushing at this repo.
But, android studio pushes to first `user1` site instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push **my repo** of `user1.visualstudio.com` to `user2.visualstudio.com`, you can try below steps:

android studio -> VCS -> import into Version Control -> import into Team Services Git -> sign out -> sign in for user2 -> select a project -> import -> update origin and import.

Answer (score 1):

On the commandline use `git remote --set-url https://user2.visualstudio.com/etc/etc/etc` then push your sources to the new repository.

If you want a full clone (with all branches and history) look at cloning git repositories.

Once you've setup your git repo in git itself, other tools will automatically pick this up.

See also:

- https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/